# Alternative to Sun SAAJ SOAP implementation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am looking for alternative SOAP (`javax.xml.soap`) implementation, other than [Sun SAAJ](http://java.net/projects/saaj). The reason for that is because I would like to deploy JAX-WS WebService on IBM JDK 5 driven Tomcat AS, but it is known problem that Sun SAAJ implementation depends on reallocated Xerces classes (see [Ref Impl does not work with IBM JDK](http://java.net/jira/browse/SAAJ-7) and [SAAJ test cases no longer work with IBM's SDK](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4228)) and the only way out for that is to use a custom Maven profile to pull `com.sun.xml.parsers:jaxp-ri` like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>pre-jdk5-profile</id>

        <activation>
            <jdk>(,1.4]</jdk>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I would like to drop this profile and simply replace SOAP implementation with one that works everywhere.

I suppose that vendor SOAP implementations may come with [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/) / [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) (which is based on IBM SOAP4J) or JBoss AS – please provide information based on my preferences:

- Implementation should be easy to separate from the rest staff (preferably one light-weighted jar).
- Implementation should support [SOAP messages with attachments](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments).
- Implementation should be Java5 bytecode compatible.
- If implementation is available in Maven Central, this is a plus.

References:

- [SOAP with Attachments API for Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments_API_for_Java)
- [How does JBossWS compare to other SOAP stacks](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWSStackComparison)
- [Alternative SOAP implementation besides those offered by Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724969)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After browsing around I have come the the following potential solution of the problem. I have explored what are the descendants of `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` using [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&k=d&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root%40jdk%24openjdk%406-b14%40javax%24xml%24soap%40MessageFactory).

Apart from standard `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl`, I have found (as supposed):

- `org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl` in [`org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:1.6.1`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/axis2/axis2-saaj/1.6.1/). This JAR correctly announces the factories via `META-INF\services\javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` and `META-INF\services\javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory` so no other tuning is needed. This version (according to Maven Central) was released in 2011, few dependencies, recommended.
- `org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl` in `org.jboss.ws.native:jbossws-native-core:3.2.1.Beta2` from JBoss 3.x. Looks to be rather old and perhaps JBoss is not supporting it's development anymore as I was able to find this jar outside maven central ([here](http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/ws/native/jbossws-native-core/3.4.0.CR3/)). A lot of dependencies, 1.8M size, not recommended.
- `org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl` in [`org.apache.openejb:openejb-webservices:4.0.0-beta-2`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/openejb/openejb-webservices/4.0.0-beta-2/) and `org.apache.geronimo.webservices.saaj.GeronimoMessageFactory` in [`org.apache.geronimo.modules:geronimo-webservices:3.0-M1`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/modules/geronimo-webservices/3.0-M1/). In reality either of these factories is a wrapper/runtime_locator for Axis2 or Sun implementations (see [`SaajFactoryFinder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openejb/openejb-webservices/4.0.0-beta-2/org/apache/openejb/server/webservices/saaj/SaajFactoryFinder.java?av=f) and [`SAAJFactoryFinder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.modules/geronimo-webservices/3.0-M1/org/apache/geronimo/webservices/saaj/SAAJFactoryFinder.java?av=f)). Not to be considered.

Bottom line: The only acceptable alternative is Axis2 implementation.

Comment: That might work. If you don't have success with Axis2 you could look into using Spring WS which should work on JDK's from 1.4 up.

Comment: (unfortunately) From [spring-ws-parent-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-parent/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-ws-parent-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom): `<dependency><groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId><artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId><version>1.3.2</version></dependency>` which is a signal that perhaps Spring-WS utilizes Sun SAAJ and they somehow workaround the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know the answer to your exact question, I have a solution how you can make Sun SAAJ (and JAX-WS RI) work under JRE 1.5. The reason why there are troubles with running JAX-WS RI under Java 5 is indeed the outdated JAXP (Java 1.5 comes with JAXP 1.3, while JAX-WS RI requires JAXP 1.4), AND because JAX-WS RI is hard-coded to use the Sun JAXP RI (com.sun.org.apache...). Since JAXP 1.3 is part of the JRE, you can't simply replace it (you can replace the implementation, but not the API).
The solution is the activesoap's xerces port, which is a cut-down JAXP 1.4 version that uses Sun JAXP RI package naming (com.sun.org.apache.).
You can find it in the Maven repo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>activesoap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't mind the strange package naming - just try it.

This is often all that's needed to run the Sun JAX-WS RI (and SAAJ as part of it) under Java 5.

Don't forget NOT to include any JAXP API JARs. They will conflict with the Java 5 JAXP API.

Comment: **rustyx**, thank you for your efforts, but your answer goes into wrong direction. The profile I have mentioned does exactly what you suggest: if pulls Sun Xerces implementation and thus solves the problem under 1.5

Comment: 1) why not always include the jaxp jar? 2) are you sure you can simply swap out SAAJ without moving to a another JAX-WS stack??

Comment: 1) Having several Xerces in your classpath is not good and may lead to problems which are difficult to trace, as at certain moment I don't know what Xerces are used. 2) I don't know. If that is not possible I hope the community will say so. On the other hand I see no problem in `javax.xml.soap` having another implementations. Why this should force me to switch to another stack?

Answer (score 0):

Tough one. Perhaps look at one of the Apache CXF releases. http://cxf.apache.org/

You may want to try flipping the classloader, bundling the jars that you need with your web app and loading in a PARENT_LAST model. This is probably your best bet.

A third option in Tomcat could be the Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism supported in Java, and Tomcat. `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS`

See here, I think it applied to older versions of Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML_Parsers_and_Java.

Comment: I know that SAAJ implementation should be in CXF, but how to utilize it? What jars to use? (well, there is no need to put them into `endorsed` as I use IBM JDK, which is not packaged with SAAJ).

Comment: It has been a few years but I had to do something similar on Websphere.  flipped the classloader to parent last and had to include some of the core jars that conflicted with my web service. I can't remember the exact jars I had to include. I started with the jaxp runtime and had to run back in a process of elimination.

Comment: I think, I have found the approval of my theory :) Check my answer.